# Dispatch async action and getState right after the value is updated in an utility function Redux JS

Tags: javascript, redux

I have a synchronous flow

```
const data = store.getState().data
// ... rest of the code
```

If `data === undefined` I like to to get it and store in `data const` similar to this

```
const data = store.getState().data || getData()
// wait till the data not undefined
// ... rest of the code
```

`getData()` is just a wrapper for the `dispatch({ type: GET_DATA_ASYNC })`

since this dispatch is `async` it will be caught and executed by a `saga watcher` and the data object will be updated.

My problem that I can't figured out how to handle this gracefully, to be clear, I want to:

get value from the store

if there is no value - request store update (by already existing action)

when the this particular value is updated - get it back

and store it in the `data const`

BTW: This is all happening in an external util function

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React hooks, you can use the useSelector hook from "react-redux". 
This hook allows you to directly access the store and get the data whenever the store is updated.

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function Test() {
    const data = useSelector(store => store.__reducerVariable_name__);
    console.log(data);
    // ...
    return data;
}
```

Comment: `This is all happening in an external util function`

Comment: I updated the code. You need to write the util function like this and call it wherever you need it!

Comment: @ShubhamGupta if this is a general-purpose util function, then it cannot use hooks such as `useSelector`. Hooks can only be used when rendering a function component.